# Port WCF SOAP service to REST service: How to implement user/password/token authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, rest, soap

I've got a WCF service provided with a SOAP endpoint with the following service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
string Login(string sAuthUserName, string sAuthUserPassword);

[OperationContract]
Consumer GetData(string sAuthKey);

[OperationContract]
bool Logout(string sAuthKey);

[OperationContract]
DataSet GetSingleByRefID(string sAuthKey, int iCommand, int iRefID);
```

Calling Login() checks the provided sAuthUserName and sAuthUserPassword an generates a hash (sAuthKey) which will be further used for authentication.

How to port this to REST?
Using the following addresses?

```
/session/{sAuthUserName}/{sAuthUserPassword} [POST]
```

would be Login()

```
/consumer/{sAuthKey} [GET]
```

would be GetData()

```
/session/{sAuthKey}/ [DELETE]
```

would be Logout()

```
/data/single/{sAuthKey}/{iCommand}/{iRefID} [GET]
```

would be GetSingleByRefID()

Which is the best way to authenticate with username and password?
This should be only required once? And after that the REST-Consumer should be able to authenticate with it's AuthKey..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar situation and use header for auth related values (username, password, auth-key in your case). The auth related methods are called without any parameters. Communication happens over secure transport.

You can access header values like below

```
HttpRequestMessageProperty httpProperties;
string sAuthKey = default(string);
if (OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpProperties))
{
    sAuthKey = httpProperties.Headers["sAuthKey"];
}
```